# Fixed price per attribute combination

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product

I have a configurable product which uses two (or even more) attributes - material and size.
Each combination of these attributes has an individual price without any mathematical reason, so I can't use super attributes.

Is there any (most preferably native) way to achieve this?

All posts I found about this issue are pretty old or unanswered and most of them suggest https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple which hasn't been updated for over 4 years now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this Extension working in 1.9 you need to change some line

steps shown below url

http://teition.com/price-indexer-will-not-re-index-in-magento/

and also move file From base/default to your theme this things work for me 1.9.2.1 and also work in 1.9.2.4

Please try and let me know

Comment: You are always welcome